# How do I customize the App icon that appears in MSAL v2 myapps.microsoft.com?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-mobile-services, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Unlike the Azure AD portal, where I can assign icons to individual apps (215px by 215px), [the MSAL portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList) only allows a 50px by 50 px image.

Changing the image in the MSAL portal does not result in a change to the icons displayed in either app

Portals:

- myapps.microsoft.com
- https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/r#/applications

Both my AzureAD app, and the MSAL converged app are Web/Trusted applications, and have the same flow.

(The native clients, don't appear in the portal for either endpoint version)

In addition MSALv2 applications return the following error when configured in myapps.microsoft.com.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The logo of [MSAL portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/application/) must be a transparent 48 x 48 or 50 x 50 pixel image in a GIF, PNG or JPEG file that is 15 KB or smaller.

I am able to reproduce the issue with same error message that not able to navigate to the V2.0 apps through the Azure Access panel and I am trying report this issue.

> The native clients, don't appear in the portal for either endpoint version

I could see the native apps which I grant consent shows up as the figure below. Please ensure the account that you login Azure Access panel have grant the consent to the native app successfully.
[image]